# How to get route parameters in Laravel Global Middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have global middleware and i need to get parameters from the routes defined in `routes.php`. My `$request->route()` is `NULL`

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The route has not been matched yet. Route parameters are only available in route middleware.

Think about it: it doesn't make much sense for a global middleware to have access to the route's parameters, since every route has different parameters.

---

You *can* however get the URI segments:

```php
$id = $request->segment(2);
```

Pass it the number (1 based index) of the segment you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Simply grouped the routes.

Comment: When using url based translation (e.g: `http://somedomain.tld/en/about`) all routes share the same parameter, which could be called `{lang}`. It would then make sense to be able to access this parameters in the middleware... And be able to restrict it to a pattern using `->where(['lang' => '[a-z]{2}])` for example...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make your middleware "global" manually.

**Way #1**

Put it into all `$middlewareGroups` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        //...
        YourGlobalMiddleware::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        //...
        YourGlobalMiddleware::class,        
    ],
];
```

**Way #2**

Wrap all your routes into a group and assign your middleware to it:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'your_global_middleware'], function () {
    //all your routes
});
```